# Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'. How can I convert/parse this?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am trying to get a simple string from my database using an Observable. I've done it like this before and haven't had any problems.

Configuration is a simple object with just an `id: number` and a `name: string`.

I'm calling this function from a ForkJoin.

Here is my code:

```
  private getMaxSeconds() {

  let maxSeconds = this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS_VIDEOGRAMMETRY_SMALL')
    .subscribe(config => {
      maxSeconds = config.value;
    }, error => console.log(error));

    return maxSeconds;
  }
```

ForkJoin code(reduced version):

```
forkJoin([
        this.getMaxSeconds(),
      ]).subscribe(response => {
        this.MaxSeconds= response[0] as string;
});
```

But this time, I'm getting this error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.`

The only difference is that now I am declaring the variable with let in the function.

How can I convert or parse this `Suscription` into a `string`?

I'm using TypeScript 4, Angular 8 and Laravel 4 for the API.

Comment: No shot you’ve ever done it like this unless you were working with mocked / synchronously available observables. This is a misunderstanding of how observables / async code works

Comment: I have done but not from a function. I'm calling this function from a ForkJoin. I updated the question.

Comment: @AlbertoValerio: Please don't post code snippets as screenshots. It makes it very difficult to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelD i'm editing right now.

Comment: @AlbertoValerio: Also post the `forkJoin` if possible. There might be better solutions for the issue.

Comment: @MichaelD Edited! ForkJoin added.

Comment: @AlbertoValerio: I've updated the answer to use with `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't declaring the variable in the function but straight up initializing it with the subscription. Instead you need to declare it. Try the following

```js
private getMaxSeconds() {
  let maxSeconds: string;

  this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS').subscribe(
    config => {
      maxSeconds = config.value;
   },
    err => { }
  );

  return maxSeconds;     // <-- WRONG! Will return `undefined`
```

And you cannot return the async variable `maxSeconds` synchronously like you're trying. By the time the `return` statement is executed, `maxSeconds` wouldn't be initialized yet and it'll return undefined. Instead any statements that depend on the async call `get('MAX_SECONDS')` should be inside the subscription.

You could find more information about asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

#### Update: use with `forkJoin`

RxJS `forkJoin` takes in observables as arguments, so can directly use `this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS')`. And if you wish to use only the `value` from it's notification, you can pipe in a `map` to it.

Try the following

```js
forkJoin(
  this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS').pipe(map(res => res['value'])),
  // 2nd observable,
  // 3rd observable
).subscribe(
  ([value, res2, res3]) => {
    console.log(value);    // <-- `value` property from `this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS')`
    console.log(res2);     // <-- notification from 2nd observable argument
    console.log(res3);     // <-- notification from 3rd observable argument
  },
  err => { }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be 2 things that I can see.

1.) The this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS') method returns a string and not an observable.
2.) The getMaxSeconds() expects a subscription to be returned (I think this is the issue).

To address the issues below:

1.) You can update the this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS') to return an observable by wrapping what is returned with the rxjs `of` operator.  This will create an observable with the value passed as the parameter.

2.) If you need an observable of type string to be returned from the getMaxSeconds() call, you can try to update the method to the code below.  Also, as a side note, you will want to complete and unsubscribe on the subscription when the component is destroyed.  There are several ways to do this with different operators (take, takeUntil, takeWhile) or creating property for the subscription and calling unsubscribe() when the component is destroyed.

```
private getMaxSeconds(): Observable<string> {
  return this.configurationRemoteService.get('MAX_SECONDS').pipe(
    map(config => config.value),
    catchError(() => // handle error)
  );
}
```