# Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Angular

Tags: angular

This is my Subscription variables which is getting the api from configuration settings

```
public ChannelsAPI=this._configservice.getConfiguration("ChannelAPI").subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

This is my _Configservice.getConfiguration method

```
  getConfiguration(key) {
    return this._http.get('./assets/config/' + this._env + '.json').map(res => {
        this.result = res.json();
        return this.result[key];
    });
}
```

This is where i am getting the error
**this.ChannelsApi suspect string but it is getting subscription thats why i am getting the error**

```
  getChannels(): Observable<Channeldata[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Channeldata[]>(this.ChannelsAPI)      >>>>  *ERROR PLACE*
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    )
  }
```

Comment: I asked same question weeks ago.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956168/error-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-subscription-how-can-i-convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the httpClient get method takes a string, getConfiguration returns an observable of probably string. At the moment you are actually setting channelsApi to be the result of a subscription, hence you get the error cannot assign subscription to string. To get around this there are 2 ways you can either go the route of settting channelsApi in the subscribe so

```
this._configservice.getConfiguration("ChannelAPI")
.subscribe((result) => this.channelsApi = result);
```

or you can just do a switch map in get channels if you're happy to do that step multiple times.

```
getChannels(): Observable<Channeldata[]> {
    return this._configservice.getConfiguration("ChannelAPI")
    .pipe(
      switchMap((r) => this.httpClient.get<Channeldata[]>(r))
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `this.httpClient.get<Channeldata[]>(this.ChannelsAPI)` with `this.ChannelsAPI` as you already have prepared whole request inside this variable. The `get` method in `HttpClient` requires passing a string.